# Pandas turns mysql int into float64

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm using psql to create a dataframe from mysql.

However I'm getting float64 instead of ints.

I read this is because of missing values, but in mysql I put the standard value already on 0 so there are no missing values anymore.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

When checking with Pandas I see a NaN in the dataframe, but I don't see this in MySQL. How can this happen? I used to have NULL as standard value but I changed this in 0 because of the error.

Comment: are you sure that there are no nulls in the column? show your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

This should convert your data back to int.

```
df['your_df_column_name'] = df['your_df_column_name'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```